# Trouble reading file in eclipse

Tags: erlang

I'm trying to read in a file inside of eclipse for a little project. I have the txt file in the same src folder

[image]

but whenever I try running this code:

```
-module(main).

%% ====================================================================
%% API functions
%% ====================================================================
-export([reader/0]).

%% ====================================================================
%% Internal functions
%% ====================================================================
reader() -> 
    {ok, Binary} = file:read_file("sequence.txt"),
    io:format(Binary).
```

I receive this error:

[image]

line 16 is the read in file line. I have read up that the error is due to no file found, if im not mistaken. However, I'm a little confused it can't find the txt file because its in the exact same directory. Does anyone know how to resolve this? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eclipse you should be able to change your "working directory". This is the directory first visible to the project when it is opened. Make sure to change it to the same where the text file is, or copy the text file into that directory. Usually it is a `build/` or `debug/` or `release/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

stupid me... Forgot to run this line:

```
{ok, CurrentDirectory} = file:get_cwd()
```

which showed me that the current directory was just the eclipse folder in my downloads. Not the workspace